# Filtering a map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of entries ,where entry has studentId and subjectId attributes.

```
List<Candidate> candidates
class Candidate {
 ...
String studentId;
String subjectId;
}
```

The objective is to  derive a map of subjectId to list of studentIds,for those subjects which have been subscribed to by MORE than one student.
I can obviously create a temporary map by iterating over the candidates(a big count),remove single entries later - which seems a costly route.
Any other suggestions ?
We are using Java 1.7

Comment: Big to you or big for the computer? As long as your solution has the right order (big O)... There aren't that many schools with millions of students...

Comment: You are doing this as a learning exercise and your school is _still_ using Java 7 after it has been obsolete for many years? Java 8 is already 4 years old. Why doesn't the school upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'costly', it's not exactly clear what you mean. - but I'll make an attempt.

With `Java8`, you can use the `groupingBy` construct to create a

```
Map<String, List<Candidate> groupedResults = candidates.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Candidate::getSubjectId));
```

and then simply filter out the entries where size <= 1.  Rather simple and since it uses streams, memory efficiency should not be an issue.

Comment: I think `Map<String, List<String>` should be `Map<String, List<Candidate>>`

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302577/3992939) answer (corrected and completed) :

```
Map<String, Integer> map = candidates.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Candidate::getSubjectId))
        .entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue().size()>1)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue().size()));
```

You could also use `candidates.parallelStream()`.